# dynamic configuration of dashboard class in extjs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

Dynamic configuration of dashboard class.
I send the configuration data when i create a object of dashboard class 
but an error occurred i.e. '[Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: part.{'.

I am new in extjs so please suggest me.

Thanks,
Prince

Comment: Can you provide more information? Where are you setting the data? Code of your factory method? Where in the page cycle?

Comment: The problem has been resolve,var dynamic_data_dashboard = Ext.create('AppsBoard.view.dashboard.Dashboard',{maxColumns: no_of_column,columnWidths: column_width,parts: dashboard_parts,defaultContent:dashboard_default_content});